# MappingException when i try to use my Entity class as ORM user provide

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have 5 connections to databases, described in config.yml, and mapping:

```
orm:
    default_entity_manager: site
    entity_managers:
        site:
            connection: siteConfig
            mappings:
                CSSBundle: ~
        forum:
            connection: forumConfig
            mappings:
                IPBBridgeBundle: ~
```

I'm use CSSBundle as primary bundle with some Entites, and use IPBBridgeBundle for authentication through IPB database ("forum" EM).
In IPBBridgeBundle i have Member entity, that i set as user provider in security.yml

```
providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: Telnet\IPBBridgeBundle\Entity\Member, property: username }
```

All of the routes handled by CSSBundle except "/login", "/ligin_check" and "/logout", they're handled by IPBBridgeBundle (LoginController). And when i try to go to / i have

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Cannot redeclare class telnet\ipbbridgebundle\controller\logincontroller in /var/www/vhosts/css.ilimnet.ru/www/Symfony/vendor/jms/di-extra-bundle/JMS/DiExtraBundle/HttpKernel/ControllerInjectorsWarmer.php on line 52
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File     /var/www/vhosts/css.ilimnet.ru/www/Symfony/vendor/jms/di-extra-bundle/JMS/DiExtraBundle/HttpKernel/ControllerInjectorsWarmer.php

is apparently declaring a class called logincontroller. Since class names in PHP are not case sensitive it collides with your self-defined login clontroller class.

Refactor your login controller classname and file to a unique name and you should be fine with this one.

The error message you mentioned above provides you the exact location of the first class occurrence.

```
 Previously declared in ...
```

Comment: Ok, renamed it to ForumLoginController, but now i have this error - `MappingException: The class 'Telnet\IPBBridgeBundle\Entity\Member' was not found in the chain configured namespaces Telnet\CSSBundle\Entity` on any path i go, even if doesn't exists

Comment: Are you sure it's IPBBridgeBundle and not IPBridgeBundle?

Comment: Yes, i sure, because IPB forum, I've checked anythin, where is **IPBBridgeBundle**